# Sending Emacs mail displays domain's front page

Tags: emacs, gnus

This is a weird one. I had Emacs email set up just the way I wanted it and it was working fine. Now, whenever I send an email (C-x m), it seems to turn the email address into a url request. If I mail a test message like this (some info redacted):

```
To: redacted@gmail.com
Subject: Test 3
From: Danny <danny@redacted.com>
--text follows this line--
Testing
```

Emacs displays the Google search page, I think using eww.
The messages buffer also displays this:

```
Sending via mail...
Contacting host: gmail.com:80
Sending...done
```

Nothing in my config has changed and email was happily sending before yesterday. I still have my authinfo files in place.

I have a split MX. My domain is hosted by another provider but my email flows through gmail. It still works fine via the web interface.

I wonder if something changed on the gmail side.

Has anyone else had this problem?

Backtrace data:

```
* eww("mailto:danny%40redacted?subject=Test&body=...")
  eww-browse-url("mailto:danny%40redacted?subject=Test&body=..." nil)
  apply(eww-browse-url "mailto:danny%redacted?subject=Test&body=..." nil)
  browse-url("mailto:danny%40redacted?subject=Test&body=...")
  mailclient-send-it()
  message-use-send-mail-function()
  message--default-send-mail-function()
  message-multi-smtp-send-mail()
  message--send-mail-maybe-partially()
  message-send-mail(nil)
  message-send-via-mail(nil)
  message-send(nil)
  message-send-and-exit(nil)
  funcall-interactively(message-send-and-exit nil)
  call-interactively(message-send-and-exit nil nil)
  command-execute(message-send-and-exit)
```

Comment: If it's using eww then the buffer would be in `eww-mode`.  Is that the case?  If so, try `M-x debug-on-entry RET eww RET` and I suspect you'll get a backtrace showing you what's happening (and you can add the backtrace to your question if it's not enough information to figure out the issue).  I don't use gnus or gmail myself, so that's about all I can suggest.

Comment: Hi @phils. Thanks for this. I didn't know about `M-x debug-on-entry`. It is indeed dropping into eww. I have updated the question with the backtrace for anyone else that wants to see, but I will keep working on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sooo, I had commented out all the text in my init file that handled email, apparently as part of an experiment that I hadn't cleaned up. That included `(require 'smtpmail)`. SMH.

On the upside, it was `M-x debug-on-entry` that helped me work it out, so I guess I learned something while making a fool of myself today :-)